# perl: How to pass a string and 2 hash in a function?

Tags: function, perl

here is my function, I have tried this but how can I transform back altid_go and obs_go into hash ??

```
go_formatting($gene_description[$idx], \%altid_go, \%obs_go);

sub go_formatting {

 my $go_description = shift;
    my $altid_go = shift;
    my $obs_go = shift;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html if you're not familiar with using references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to, just use references. Anywhere you'd write with hash `$altid_go{hash_key}` use `$altid_go->{hash_key}` with reference inside your function.

You can alias to "real" hash with [`Data::Alias`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Alias) and built-in method linked from there, but considering level of your question you shouldn't go there at the moment.